# Ember POST 405 (Not Allowed) w/ Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ember.js, ember-cli

I am getting a `POST https://heroku_client_path.herokuapp.com/login 405 (Not Allowed)` for an Ember.js app with a Rails api (both on heroku)

When processing a login or sign up. I feel the Request URL should be the heroku server path /login as I set my `ADAPTER_URL` heroku config var, and not the heroku client URL shown above.

I believe I have CORS setup correctly.

I am using Ember-CLI. I hand rolled the auth it is not Simple-Auth.

environment.js:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'client-rantly',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/',
    adapterURL: process.env.ADAPTER_URL,
    locationType: 'auto',
    EmberENV: {
      FEATURES: {
      }
    },
  }; 

  if (environment === 'development') {
  }

  if (environment === 'production') {   
  }

  return ENV;
};
```

adapters/application.js:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import ENV from '../config/environment';

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  host: ENV.adapterURL || ENV.ADAPTER_URL,
  headers: function () {
    return {
      'auth_token': localStorage.getItem('authToken')
    };
  }.property('authToken')
});
```

brocfile.js

```
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

var app = new EmberApp({
  dotEnv: {
    clientAllowedKeys: ['ADAPTER_URL']
  }
});
module.exports = app.toTree();
```

controllers/application.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['search'],
  isAuthenticated: false,

  init: function() {
    var authToken = localStorage.getItem('authToken');
    if(authToken) {
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
    }
  },

  actions: {

    login: function () {
      var credentials = {
        email: this.get('email'),
        password: this.get('password')
      };

      this.set('errorMessage', null);
      return Ember.$.post('login', credentials).then(function(response){
        this.set('errorMessage', response.error);
        if (response.auth_token) {
          localStorage.setItem('authToken', response.auth_token);
          localStorage.setItem('userId', response.user_id);
          this.set('isAuthenticated', true);
          location.reload();
        }
      }.bind(this));
    },
  }
});
```

cors rails side - config/application.rb

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)
require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module ServerRantly
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.active_record.raise_in_transactional_callbacks = true
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')

    config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors", :debug => true, :logger => (-> { Rails.logger }) do
      allow do
        origins '*'

        resource '/cors',
          :headers => :any,
          :methods => [:post],
          :credentials => true,
          :max_age => 0

        resource '*',
          :headers => :any,
          :methods => [:get, :post, :delete, :put, :options, :head],
          :max_age => 0
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks like a rails issue.   Have you tested the backend with postman or curl?     Is the route present?  Are you trying to request html when it should be json?

Comment: @user2105103 I have tested with postman and it processes the POST request just fine. It returns the correct JSON response. Though with the rails server URL which is the one not being sent. Even tried hard coding the full URL in place of 'login' for that action in the controller with no luck.

Comment: Could you try to use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) extension for chrome in order to escape CORS investigation?

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
adapterURL: process.env.ADAPTER_URL
```

Where is `process.env.ADAPTER_URL` defined?

It seems like you are on the right track with overriding `host` on the `ActiveModelAdapter` adapter to use your non-client URL.

Comment: Locally it points to localhost, though on Heroku I have it pointing at my rails server also hosted on Heroku which is why I find it odd that even with it pointing at that it still runs the POST against the Ember client URL.